# Different opacity element within a div

Tags: html, css, opacity

I need to change opacity of an element within a div, to give it more opacity than the parent. How can I give the `.solid` a full opacity (`="1"`), without pre-processors?

```css
.half-faded {
  opacity:0.3;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.solid {
  opacity:1; /* doesn't help */
  opacity:2; /* twice doesn't help */
}
```

```html
<div class="half-faded">
  <span class="one">One</span>
  <span class="two">Two</span>
  <span class="solid">Solid</span>
  <span class="four">Four</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't. you should make it so that the elements themselves have the opacity and change it per item. If you want the background to be clear-ish then use `RGBA` or the `HSVA`

Comment: When you change the opacity of a container, you are changing it for the whole container, including children. What is the purpose of the semi-transparent container? If its just for a semi-transparent look, then do as @Jhecht suggests. Otherwise let us know if you have a specific reason for doing it this way.

Comment: If the parent has a 0.3 opacity, the max opacity the children will "seem" to have is 0.3. And I write "seem" with quotes because actually the children have opacity of 1 (i.e. the default value), that's why setting it to 1 (or 2 which is an invalid value), as you tried, didn't work.

Comment: You guys, I chucked in `opacity:2;` just for the puns :)) Thanks for the answers. The problem is that I have `img`s, `span`s, `div`s within `divs`, etc in that parent div, and I have to single on one item and change its opacity. To change opacity of individual elements is a nightmare for both the UI and backend, I was hoping for a quick resolution.. Thanks for pointing out that there is none :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `.half-faded` has multiple elements (not just `span`s), you could do:

```
.half-faded > * {
  opacity: .3;
}

.half-faded > .solid {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**[Edit]**

The only way to do what you asked in the comment is to wrap the "Solid" text inside a `<span>` for example, as shown in the snippet below. The reason is that the `.half-faded > .solid` rule turns the opacity of the `.solid` elements back to 1, so we would have to turn down the opacity of the text outside the `.biz` element back to `0.3`, however there's no CSS rule to match text nodes, therefore you need to have the text inside an element.

If you're able to change how the markup is built, I think it'd be easier to change the way it's being built.

```css
.half-faded > * {
  opacity: .3;
  display: block;
}

.half-faded > .solid {
  opacity: 1;
}

.half-faded > .solid > span {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-faded">
  <div>Not solid</div>
  <a class="solid">Solid</a>
  <span class="solid">
    <span>Inside solid but not solid</span>
    <a href="#" class="biz">Solid business</a>  
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ingenious. Standing ovation.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```css
.half-faded {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.half-faded * {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.half-faded .solid {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-faded">
  <span class="one">One</span>
  <span class="two">Two</span>
  <span class="solid">Solid</span>
  <span class="four">Four</span>
  <div>other</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comment.

The black background is to show that it is see-thru.

```css
body{
background-color:black;
}

.half-faded {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border:1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.half-faded span{
opacity:0.3;
}
.solid {
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-faded">
  <span class="one">One</span>
  <span class="two">Two</span>
  <span class="solid">Solid</span>
  <span class="four">Four</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice example, but maybe a colour other than black would show it more clearly? It's a bit hard to see, there :)

Comment: Why did you need the background color? What if I just delete the two `background-color` lines?

Comment: The `.half-faded` is there to make the background of the element see thru. The black background is to show the opacity of the half faded as well as the unfaded opacity of the solid element.

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` property can only accept numbers between 0 and 1, so `opacity: 2` is invalid. The problem is that you're trying to change `opacity` of child element (it's already have `opacity: 1`). The increasing `opacity` of child element will not solve the issue, you need to change `opacity` property of `.half-faded` element.